# jquery - how to clone last section

Tags: jquery

how do i set my jquery code to clone only the last section?

So next click will give me : `<section id="unit4">cc</section>`

JQUERY

```
$("#addUnit").click(function () {
    // Clone the last SECTION 
    var new_section = $('section').XXXXXXXXXX.clone().fadeIn("slow");
    new_section.attr("id", "unit"+unitCount);


    $('section').last().after(new_section);
    unitCount = unitCount+1;
});
```

HTML

```
<section id="unit1">aa</section>
<section id="unit2">bb</section>
<section id="unit3">cc</section>
<p>
    <button type="button" id="addUnit" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
</p>
```

Comment: You already know to use `.last()` thats the answer `$('section').last().clone()....`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var new_section = $('#unit'+unitCount).clone().fadeIn("slow");
```

That will clone the latest added section to fade in.

or even you try last selector

```
var new_section = $( "section:last" ).clone().fadeIn("slow");
```